# How to set field of <T> from a List<string> with IEnumerable.Repeat

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a DTO that contains several `List<>` of other DTO that I want to initialize to a known state. Each of the DTO contains a `Description` member which I also want to initialize with default values.

**Example DTO (Typical):**

```
public class ResidentialDescriptionItemDto : EntityDto<int>
{
    ...
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**Default Settings**

```
private List<ResidentialDescriptionItemDto> _residentialDescriptionItems;

private List<string> _residentialBuildingsList = new List<string>
{
    "Living Room",
    "Kitchen",
    "Dining Room",
    "Master Bed",
    "Bedroom 2",
    "Bedroom 3",
    "Bedroom 4",
    "Bathroom 1",
    "Bathroom 2",
    "Other"
};
```

**Parent DTO Getter/Setter (Typical)**

The private backing field for each `List<T>` member has been initialized to an empty List. The Getter may not be accessed if `this` is being instantiated with entity data. In that case the setter initializes all lists and the Getter should return that data as-is.

The following logic accomplishes the above with the exception of setting List members' `.Description` property in the `Repeated<T>()` Func.

```
public virtual IList<ResidentialDescriptionItemDto> ResidentialDescriptionItems
{
    get => _residentialDescriptionItems = _residentialDescriptionItems.Any()
            ? _residentialDescriptionItems
            : Repeated(new ResidentialDescriptionItemDto(), 10, _residentialBuildingsList);
    set => _residentialDescriptionItems = value;
}


public static List<T> Repeated<T>(T value, int count, List<string> defaultLabels = null)
{
    count = defaultLabels?.Count ?? count;

    // Create list with count items.
    var ret = new List<T>(count);
    ret.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(value, count));

==>>// How can I set the .Description field of each T according to the defaultLabels parm?

    return ret;
}
```

How can I expand on Repeated() function with **short/simple** Lambda/Linq to accomplish the above?

Comment: you have to apply a generic constraint to `T` at least, to be able to access `Description` field

Comment: It's *extremely* unlikely that having a list with N references to the same object would actually be useful to you.  You almost certainly want different object instances in the list.

Comment: seem over engineered.... its not clear why you are wanting to use generics, yeah sure you can but why... if it is wanted you need to say that T is of Type which has interface which specifies property but that seems over kill for what could literally be a list passing the list of room names in a for loop. like @PavelAnikhouski said that would be the answer.

Comment: The DTO is used in a ViewModel that contains just shy of about 500 form fields. My purpose is two-fold. To keep similar functionality centralized, reduce the amount of code performing the same logic. Yes, Interfaces would be overkill and over engineered for sure. I have a couple dozen of these Lists that need the same logic.

Comment: I'm also a little confused at what @Servy is saying. A `ResidentialDescriptionItemDto` makes up a ROW in a TABLE on the front end. There is a default requirement of 10 rows, or 4 rows, or whatever. They all have default strings for each row. Isn't all of this information overkill for the question itself? I'm sorry I didn't include a better outline of what my use is. Also, these default descriptions are going to be stored in a database  for backend administrators to edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create interface:

```
public interface IDescription
{
    string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Implement interface in your DTO:

```
public class ResidentialDescriptionItemDto : EntityDto<int>, IDescription
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Change method to following:

```
public static List<T> Repeated<T>(List<string> defaultLabels = null)
    where T : IDescription, new()
{
    if (defaultLabels == null)
        return new List<T>();

    return defaultLabels
        .Select(x => new T { Description = x })
        .ToList();
}
```

It works.

---

Another approach. Without interface.

```
public static List<T> Repeated<T>(
    Func<string, T> func, List<string> defaultLabels = null)
    where T : new()
{
    if (defaultLabels == null)
        return new List<T>();

    return defaultLabels
        .Select(x => func(x))
        .ToList();
}
```

`func` is Factory method.
Use it like this:

```
var result = Repeated<ResidentialDescriptionItemDto>(
    x => new ResidentialDescriptionItemDto { Description = x }, list);
```

Comment: Beautiful...bravo

Comment: Good answer: your first approach can be simplified to `return defaultLabels?.Select(x => new T { Description = x }).ToList() ?? new List<T>();`

Comment: I like the first approach. Although it seems I must not have explained the need very well. The DTO List gets initialized to a specific count with the Description fields populated with the defaultLabel strings. Ie, `list[0].Description = defaultLabels[0]` through `list[9].Description = defaultLabels[9]`. with the end result of `Repeated()` being a List<residentialDescriptionItemDto>